# Cancel Qt Installer Framework

Tags: javascript, qt, installation

I use Qt Installer Framework to create an installer for my application. Before the installation starts, the controller script checks in the TargetDirectoryPage callback, whether the program is already installed on the system and if yes, then the installer should terminate without doing anything.
But I could not find a way to stop the installer from copying (and therefore overwriting existing) files like `uninstaller.exe`, `uninstaller.ini`, `installer.dat` and some more into the target dir and from requesting elevated rights for that.

To skip the installer pages and show the error message in the finish page I use the following function in the controller script based on an official example:

```cpp
function cancelInstaller(message) {
    console.log("Cancel installer: " + message);
    // this key value pair sets the label text in the Finish page:
    installer.setValue("FinishedText", "<font color='#e53935' size=3>" + message + "</font>");
    // skip all installation pages except for the finish page
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.Introduction, false);
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.TargetDirectory, false);
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.ComponentSelection, false);
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.ReadyForInstallation, false);
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.StartMenuSelection, false);
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.PerformInstallation, false);
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.LicenseCheck, false);
    // this key value pair is for telling components that installation is canceled:
    installer.setValue("installerCanceled", true);
}
```

The value `installerCanceled` is later used in the components to skip the execution of `beginInstallation`, so that at least the component's data is not copied to the target dir.

I hope you can help me, I wasted too much time for that already. Thanks.